# call() doesn't return the correct type

Tags: typescript

I have the following typescript:

```
let fn = function (): boolean {
    return true
}

let res1: number

res1 = fn.call(null) // Should error
```

I shouldn't be allowed to assign `res1` because it's declared as `number` and the result of `fn.call()` would be `boolean`. Check in [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBAZgdhC80CuMDGYCWB7OAKAlAFwQBGWWoAhnAN4CwAUBMxAE7hKtxitIiMBfRo1CR2AZwCMxGEgC2JEK2EMJkhNBgA6VJWDBcs-fggB6UxADKACyxJgAEwhLWWVkA).

This was an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/212) but it was [fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028), so am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It seems like `.call` is defined to return `any`, which is then assignable to `string`. Not sure why, but it's interesting.

Comment: Are you using the `strictBindCallApply` compiler option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a special compiler option (which is not available in the playground) which makes `call` and `bind` and `apply` preserve correct type.

The option is `strictBindCallApply`  and you can read about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

> Enable stricter checking of the bind, call, and apply methods on functions.

With this option set to true your code will error as expected.

Comment: Wondering why it isn't enabled by default. Backwards compatibility?

Comment: @HristiyanDodov Yes. The "fixed" link you posted in your question addresses that: it could break existing code.

Comment: @HristiyanDodov yes, this is a major breaking change so it is behind a flag. If `strict` is enabled you get `strictBindCallApply` by defualt

Comment: "not available in the playground"  Yeah, [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Website/issues/12) persists.

Answer (score -1):

Quite weird. Alternatively you can directly call the function using `fn()` and it will throw compilation errors.

```
let fn = function (): boolean {
    return true
}

let res1: number
res1 = fn() // Will definitely result in error.
```

Comment: `fn(null)` is not equivalent to `fn.call(null)`. The first parameter to `call` is what should be used for the `this` object.

Comment: @crashmstr while true in the general case, the two would be equivalent here, since `fn` doesn't take any parameters, hence `fn()` and `fn(null)` do the same. Also, since it never uses the `this` context, it doesn't matter what it's set to `fn.call(null)` and `fn.call(anyValue)` are also equivalent.

Comment: @VLAZ except than in Typescript, `fn(null)` is an error. Thus, `fn(null)` and `fn.call(null)` are not equivalent (Yes, it will still compile to JavaScript and the resulting code will not behave differently, but it is still a compiler error).

Comment: The *first* compiler error in your `res1 = fn(null)` is not related at all to assigning to `res1`, but that `fn` does not take any parameters. Thus my statement that `fn(null)` is not equivalent to `fn.call(null)`. The equivalent would be `res1 = fn()`. That produces a Typescript error that the type returned by `fn()` cannot be assigned to `res1`.